# Error when scraping HTML: Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

I copied code to get stock data from hsbc derivatives. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOzHacoP-u4)

I changed the URL (to hsbc) and that I want to find the value based on the ID, not the class name.
I changed the ID name.

I get

> "Run Time Error-91:
> Object variable or With block variable not set".

```vb
Sub Get_Web_Data()    
    
    Dim request As Object
    Dim response As String
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim website As String
    Dim price As Variant
    
    ' Website to go to.
    website = "https://www.hsbc-zertifikate.de/home/details#!/isin:DE000TR8S293"
    
    ' Create the object that will make the webpage request.
    Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    ' Where to go and how to go there - probably don't need to change this.
    request.Open "GET", website, False
    
    ' Get fresh data.
    'request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    
    ' Send the request for the webpage.
    request.send
    
    ' Get the webpage response data into a variable.
    response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    
    ' Put the webpage into an html object to make data references easier.
    html.body.innerHTML = response
    
    ' Get the price from the specified element on the page.
    price = html.getElementById("kursdaten20").innerText
    
    ' Output the price into a message box.
    MsgBox price
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value you expect to see retrieved?

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for element id `kursdaten20` that does not exist on the page.
`html.getElementById("kursdaten20")` returns `Nothing` and you are accessing the `innerText` property with `Nothing/Null` reference.

When searching for element, you could add a check if the element exists:

```
'query the document
Set element = html.getElementById("kursdaten20")

If Not element Is Nothing Then
    ' Get the price from the specified element on the page.
    price = element.innerText
    ' Output the price into a message box.
    MsgBox price
Else
    ' no price
    MsgBox "no price"
End If
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the fast answer. But there is an element called "kursdaten20" on the page. See here: https://www.hsbc-zertifikate.de/home/details#!/isin:DE000TR8S293

Comment: I checked in my browser, it does not exist neither in DOM or page source. Maybe you are accessing it from a different location or have a login.

Comment: Okay, interesting! Can you tell me a valid ID so that I can test? Some stock value - id you can find or so! Many Thanks.

Comment: @luke That point is easily settled using the immediate window.  Step through until the line below `Set` is highlighted.  Then type `?request is nothing` if the result is true then the object is not being set.  If it is false then it is being set.  It may be worth double checking your references.  You're not getting a reference error but that doesn't guarantee that you have all the right references loaded.

Comment: What I receive when I ask for the data via Excel does not correspond to what I see when I access the hsbc url via a browser. It does work for Yahoo though. Try outputing the contents of the response variable to a file, and view its contents. When I do that, it seems that hsbc sends "Seite nicht verfügbar" (whereas for Yahoo it works fine).

Comment: probably hsbc is blocking roboter, like this excel vba crawler?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's more complicated than what you expected it to be.

I will assume that the info you're after is this:

> Geldkurs (1 Stuck)4,01 EUR
>
> Briefkurs (1 Stuck)4,11 EUR

These fields are not static. They are dynamically updated (I guess whenever a transaction is made) by scripts. That's why you will not find their ID's in the source code of the `HTML` page.

There is however a way to get the info you need by replicating the `HTTP request` that is being sent to the server whenever these fields are updated.

To find this request and its parameters you need to inspect the network traffic, when you load the page, using your browser's developer tools.

This request returns a (quite poorly structured IMHO) `JSON` response containing another `JSON` (!!) which contains the info you want, in `HTML` format(!!). Here's how the second `JSON` looks like:

[image]

To make things even worse, the names that you can see under `state`, change with each request you send.

So, firstly you need to parse the `json` response. Then you need to parse the `json` within the initial `json` response to get your hands on the `HTML` code. Then, using an HTML document object, you can easily get access to the `HTML` table, containing the desired information.

Here's the way to do it:

```
Option Explicit

Sub hsbc()
Dim req As New WinHttpRequest
Dim doc As New HTMLDocument
Dim table As HTMLTable
Dim cell As HTMLTableCell
Dim parsedJSON As Object
Dim key As Variant
Dim htmlCode As String
Dim url As String, reqBody As String, resp As String

url = "https://www.hsbc-zertifikate.de/web-htde-tip-zertifikate-main/?components=YW1wZWw6UnRQdWxsQ29tcG9uZW50KCdhbmltQ3NzLGMtaGlnaGxpZ2h0LXVwLGMtaGlnaGxpZ2h0LWRvd24sYy1oaWdobGlnaHQtY2hhbmdlZCcpO3NlYXJjaGhpbnRfbW9iaWxlOlNlYXJjaEhpbnRNb2JpbGVDb21wb25lbnQoJ3VsU2VhcmNoU21hbGwvc2VhcmNoSW5wdXRNb2JpbGUnKTtzZWFyY2hoaW50OlNlYXJjaEhpbnRDb21wb25lbnQoJ3VsU2VhcmNoRnVsbC9zZWFyY2gtaGVhZGVyJyk7aXNpbjpSZXNwb25zaXZlU25hcHNob3RDb21wb25lbnQoJ2ZhbHNlJyk%3D&pagepath=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.hsbc-zertifikate.de%2Fhome%2Fdetails%23!%2Fisin%3ADE000TR8S293&magnoliaSessionId=B22F70D76986AB6BACDF110E4E7A724C.public7a&v-1566551332455"
reqBody = "v-browserDetails=1&theme=hsbc&v-appId=myApp&v-sh=1080&v-sw=1920&v-cw=1920&v-ch=550&v-curdate=1566551332455&v-tzo=-180&v-dstd=60&v-rtzo=-120&v-dston=true&v-vw=50&v-vh=50&v-loc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.hsbc-zertifikate.de%2Fhome%2Fdetails%23!%2Fisin%3ADE000TR8S293&v-wn=myApp-0.5436432044490654"
With req
    .Open "POST", url, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send reqBody
    resp = .responseText
End With
Set parsedJSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(resp)
Set parsedJSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(parsedJSON("uidl"))
For Each key In parsedJSON("state").Keys
    If parsedJSON("state")(key)("contentMode") = "HTML" Then
        htmlCode = htmlCode & parsedJSON("state")(key)("text")
    End If
Next key
doc.body.innerHTML = htmlCode
Set table = doc.getElementsByTagName("table")(0)
Debug.Print table.Rows(2).innerText
Debug.Print table.Rows(3).innerText

End Sub
```

For demonstration purposes the result will be printed in your immediate window.

[image]

You will need to add the following references to your project (VBE>Tools>References):

1. Microsoft WinHTTP Services version 5.1
2. Microsoft HTML Objects Library
3. Microsoft Scripting Runtime

You will also need to add [this JSON parser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) to your project. Follow the installation instructions in the link and you should be set to go.